# Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'. > Keystore file appfoldeer\android\app\key.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

i search everywhere but i didn't find any solution in vs code for flutter.
1-> i have release sign key which is stored in **C:\Users\username\Desktop\appfolder\android\app\key.jks** 
2-> i have key.properties file in android folder like **\android\key.properties**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\aapfolder\android\app\key.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 29s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                          
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       151.0s (!)
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

where am i wrong please help.

Comment: Could you please share your build.gradle file? It looks there's an additional character ( > ) at the end of keystore file path

Comment: i solved it yes Giuseppe Giacoppo you are right the additional character ( > ) in the end of keystore was a mistake

Answer (score -1):

**you need to sign in your app using keytool**

for more detials please visit [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)